# Why jsf can't handle jsf error pages?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I have an error page `error.jsf` mentioned in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/viewExpired.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

If the file is .jsf the error page isn't triggered, when I change it to .jsp everything is OK.
I've also implemented a filter but still nothing.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>Error</filter-name>
    <filter-class>creazione.exception.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Is it something that JSF can't handle?

UPDATE
The code from web.xml with the url-pattern mappings:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can happen if you're actually using Facelets as default view technology, as standardized in JSF 2.0. Your question history also confirms that you're using Facelets instead of its legacy predecesor JSP. You need to make those error pages Facelets files as well instead of JSP files.

That the filter is not "working" is caused by something else. Filters have totally no problem to run in combination with JSF.

Comment: Why do you mean I need the make the error pages Facelets files? If they are .jsf aren't already facelets? I don't understand...

Comment: JSP is an old view technology. Facelets (XHTML) is the successor of JSP. JSF 2.0 uses Facelets by default. The ".jsf" files do not really exist on disk. They are virtual URL mappings pointing to concrete JSP (.jsp) or Facelet (.xhtml) files. JSF 2.0 uses Facelets by default.

Comment: Although my error.xhtml page is served to me, it _not_ served through the FacesServlet. I don't know if I'm missing something here, but I am writing a servlet to use as an <error-page> in web.xml, which will redirect to my error.xhtml page.

Comment: @Markos: the URL pattern should match `FacesServlet` `<url-pattern>`. If you have `<location>/error.xhtml</location>`, then it should be mapped on `*.xhtml` to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, the Faces Servlet is mapped to *.xhtml AND the error page is error.xhtml. And I am being served the page outside the faces servlet! If I hit its URL directly, it is being served by the faces servlet, as expected. My impression is that when an exception is thrown inside the faces servlet, it is being caught and handled by the container, which forwards to my error.xhtml page, without serving it through the faces servlet.

Comment: @Markos: I've never seen that. What JSF impl/version are you using? Please check [this page](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.xhtml) for a live demo of JSF exception handling (click the "on normal request" buttons).

Comment: Mojarra 2.0. But if you say you haven't seen it, I may be doing something wrong. I will look into it, and may post a question later on. Thanks.